# How to delete all dlls from given path that already exist in the GAC using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, gac

Are there any PowerShell gurus here that know how to delete all dlls from a given path that already exist in the GAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine whether an assembly is already in the GAC by name with:

```
$AssemblyName = [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName("C:\Path\to\assembly.dll")
$IsInGAC = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoad($AssemblyName).GlobalAssemblyCache
```

You could wrap that in a test function to filter your input assemblies:

```
function Test-GACPresence {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='Path')]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='LiteralPath',ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('PsPath')]
        [string]$LiteralPath
    ) 

    $LiteralPath = if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Path'){
        (Resolve-Path $Path).ProviderPath
    } else {
        (Resolve-Path $LiteralPath).ProviderPath
    }

    try{
        return [System.Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoad([System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($LiteralPath)).GlobalAssemblyCache
    }
    catch{
        return $false
    }
}

$ExistsInGAC = Get-ChildItem "path\to\test" -Filter *.dll -Recurse |?{$_|Test-GACPresence}
$ExistsInGAC |Remove-Item
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the end ? Probably it should be remove-item and not remote-item.

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen this has been working great, however, I don' think it only takes into considering the assembly file name and not assembly file version? Do you mind offering some guidance for checking the assembly file version aswell?

Comment: Just looping @MathiasR.Jessen back in as I am not sure if reference above worked